# fedora 28 login fails after fstransform ext4 to xfs

Tags: authentication, arm, raspberry-pi3, xfs, fedora-28

I have set up a sd card with fedora 28 minimal for the raspberry pi. Because I wan't to test Docker on the Pi, I have tried to convert the root partition to xfs with fstransform, what worked really well. Now when I insert the sd card to the Pi, the system boots like normal. At first boot, the system-setup screen appears and i can set a root password and also create a new user (without password for testing). After the setup I try to login with both users, but directly after the login I get logged out again.

The part of the system log for the login on the sd card looks like this:

```
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_AUTH pid=951 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostn
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_ACCT pid=951 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: CRED_ACQ pid=951 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=loca
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_ROLE_CHANGE pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='pam: default-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 selected-context=unconfin
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd-logind[640]: New session 11 of user root.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 11 of user root.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty6.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[953]: USER_ACCT pid=953 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[953]: USER_ROLE_CHANGE pid=953 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='pam: default-context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 selected
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[953]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[953]: USER_START pid=953 uid=0 auid=0 ses=12 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_selinux,pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_s
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[953]: AVC avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=953 comm="(systemd)" path="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" dev="mmcblk0p4" ino=16969648 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=u
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[953]: user@0.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[953]: user@0.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/systemd/systemd: Permission denied
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: user@0.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 0.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=user@0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? te
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost login[951]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@0.service failed with 'failed'
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost login[951]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_START pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_console,pam_selinux,pam_namespace,pa
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: CRED_REFR pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost addr=? ter
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_LOGIN pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost addr=? terminal=tty6 res=success'
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost login[951]: ROOT LOGIN ON tty6
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[955]: AVC avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=955 comm="login" path="/usr/bin/bash" dev="mmcblk0p4" ino=33781637 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unc
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: CRED_DISP pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=localhost addr=? ter
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost login[951]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[951]: USER_END pid=951 uid=0 auid=0 ses=11 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_selinux,pam_loginuid,pam_console,pam_selinux,pam_namespace,pam
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='unit=getty@tty6 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=?
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: getty@tty6.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: getty@tty6.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Aug 25 09:15:46 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty6.
```

When I try to ssh to the Pi I get a broken pipe.

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.20.150 port 22: Broken pipe
```

At this time i have checked on permissions on the file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd, but they are set right:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root     4096 25. Apr 08:17 systemd
```

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Can you access via ssh without executing docker? Are you acceding to host or docker using ssh? Is possible that 192.168.20.150 is your docker IP and there's no SSH server inside container?
Let's clarify these question and let's see

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that this is a new flashed sd card with fedora 28 minimal for arm. By default the root partition is formatted with ext4. I flashed the sd card and then right after I transformed the root partition to xfs. So there is no additional software installed.

Comment: After some more reading at the fedora page I figured out that the server verion of fedora 28 has by default an xfs partition as root partition. With this Image flashed, the rpi 3 runs well.